# Select item from multiple select menu

Tags: javascript

This is a strange bug I have in my script.

When I click the option "Test", the `alert` appears.

However when I select it (using the control key) it doesn't `alert`.

As a test, ctrl select 'Desktop' then click 'Test'. You'll see no Alert :(

Why is this?

*JS:*

```
var $cb = document.querySelector("#equipments");

$cb.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if ($cb.value == "test") {
        // if true 
        alert("Selected!");
    } else {
        // false 
    }
})
```

*HTML*

```
<select id="equipments" name="equipments[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" multiple data-live-search="true" required>
  <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
  <option value="desktop">Desktop</option>
  <option value="test" >Test</option>
  <option value="none">None</option>
</select>
```

*Fiddle:* https://jsfiddle.net/0mvngqsc/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The change event does not define `ctrlKey`, as you have noted.
change is an event which uses the base event interface, which does not handle ctrlKey. To have ctrlKey defined, you need to use a `TouchEvent`, `MouseEvent`, or KeyboardEvent.

Answer (score 1):

there is a property called `selectedOptions` which gives us the object of the selected items.i am just iterating through that object using `for of`.unfortunately couldn't get it working on change event.i hope this helps you to reach your results

```js
    var $cb = document.querySelector("#equipments").selectedOptions;
    var $sb = document.querySelector("#submit");


    $sb.addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (let el in $cb) {
            console.log($cb[el].value);
            if ($cb[el].value == "test") {
                // if true 
                alert("Selected!");
            }
            else {

                // false 
            }


        }


    })
```

```html
<select id="equipments" name="equipments[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" multiple
        data-live-search="true" required>
        <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
        <option value="desktop">Desktop</option>
        <option value="test">Test</option>
        <option value="none">None</option>
    </select>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Appreciate you trying Umair : )